# Golang docker container doesn't start on Windows Home

Tags: windows, docker, go

I'm using Windows Home OS with WSL enabled in Docker.

After **build** message below is printed

```
docker build .
SECURITY WARNING: You are building a Docker image from Windows against a non-    Windows Docker host. All files and directories added to build context will have '-rwxr-    xr-x' permissions. It is recommended to double check and reset permissions for sensitive files and directories.
```

When I try to **run** image message below is printed

```
docker run 49fee6f5a6bb -d
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:349: starting container process caused "exec: \"-d\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
```

Dockerfile content is below

```
FROM golang:alpine
# Set necessary environmet variables needed for our image
ENV GO111MODULE=on \
    CGO_ENABLED=0 \
    GOOS=linux \
    GOARCH=amd64

# Move to working directory /build
WORKDIR /build

# Copy and download dependency using go mod
COPY go.mod .
COPY go.sum .
RUN go mod download

# Copy the code into the container
COPY . .

# Build the application
RUN go build -o main .

# Move to /dist directory as the place for resulting binary folder
WORKDIR /dist

# Copy binary from build to main folder
RUN cp /build/main .

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 3000

# Command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/dist/main"]
```

Comment: The base image is a Linux is , that's why you are getting the warning

Comment: Is `-d` supposed to be the `docker run` "detach" option?  It needs to be _before_ the image ID; if it's after the image ID, it's taken as the command to run.

Comment: @DavidMaze you are right. it was a stupid misstake thank you)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the order of commands (most likely):

`docker run -d yourcontainer` should work

Some unrelated advice: This is a rewrite of your docker file (untested).
As you notice it is shorter, and uses a build and run stage.

The build stage uses a larger container with golang in there, your code, etc. The run container (`FROM alpine:latest`)only has the resulting program making it nice and small (quick to load onto your container environment), and more secure (you can use a hardend linux for example with only your code).

```
FROM golang:alpine AS build

WORKDIR /build
ADD . /build

# Depending on the golang version GO111MODULE can be removed as env variable
RUN GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 GO111MODULE=on go build -o main 

FROM alpine:latest

# Export necessary port
EXPOSE 3000
# Add  application
WORKDIR /dist
COPY --from=build /build/main /dist/main
```

Comment: Thank you. docker run -d yourcontainer solved the issue for me. Also thanks for new version of dockerfile it seems more useful than my.